# How to redirect my entire Wordpress site to non-secure "http" version

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I developed a Wordpress site for a friend, but for some reason, when anyone types the address into the address bar it takes you to the "https" version of the site. We do not have an SSL, so this generates an "Untrusted Connection" error. I have tried modifying the .htaccess file to redirect the site to the "http" version with no success. The code I used is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Still the problem persists. I also tried using a plugin, Mavis HTTPS to HTTP Redirection, but it didn't resolve the problem. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: where is the site hosted?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the wp_options table in MySQL and change the values for

1. siteurl
2. home

Comment: The values are already set to http:// in the database. I also tried the plugin, but it didn't work either. I'm really stumped here!

Comment: its loading fine, no https

Comment: It does for me as well, but we've gotten complaints that when someone actually types in the address bar "newcolorimage.com", they get the error. And when I did this on my friend's computer, it did happen. I know it's probably just a matter of already being on a secure website and when you type a new address in the address bar the browser assumes it's also "https". I'd really like to make it impossible to even view the website using "https" to completely eliminate this problem.

Comment: try this in your htacess:  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
 RewriteRule ^ http://<domain anme here>%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your .htaccess file to this (slightly edited):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried using this in the .htaccess, still the same problem

Comment: Theres a plugin here that may do the trick:

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/mavis-https-to-http-redirect/